# PIG UDF: How could I change the .jar package which has been registered?

Tags: java, jar, apache-pig, udf

I have got the .jar package registered before and the functions could be run well. But when I want to debug the PIG UDF functions, I need to change the functions, and after that I will re-generated the jar package.
But the situation is when I regenerate the jar package with updated functions and register it again, the PIG still run the original functions which is in the original jar package registered before. Even I package the jar with a new name and register again, PIG still use the original one.

So did anyone encounter with this problem? and how to solve it? Thanks a lot. I have been stuck by this problem for two days. T_T

Comment: Check the location of where you are saving the .jar file and the location from where you are registering the .jar.If these two paths are different then that is reason it is failing.

Comment: Yes. I have checked it for many times. The path is right. I  think it may because the register command cached some jar packages registered before. So no one encountered the same situation?

Answer (score 0):

I finally get this issue resolved by restart the pig -x local and then it works.